# Authorize.net Hosted payment form AcceptUI.js not returning last 4 digits card number and customer info in response object

Tags: authorize.net-cim

I am using CIM with hosted form with AcceptUI.js

As per documentation, response should have last 4 digits of credit card and customer first name and last name. But response missing both info.

I am using following button configuration

```
<button type="button"
                class="AcceptUI"
                data-billingAddressOptions='{"show":true, "required":false}'
                data-paymentOptions='{"showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": false}'
                data-apiLoginID="<?php echo addslashes($this->getMethod()->getConfigData('login')); ?>"
                data-clientKey="<?php echo addslashes($this->getMethod()->getConfigData('client_key')); ?>"
                data-acceptUIFormBtnTxt="Submit"
                data-acceptUIFormHeaderTxt="Card Information"
                data-responseHandler="acceptjsUIResponse">Add card.
        </button>
```

XHR POST https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

```
{"opaqueData":{"dataDescriptor":"COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT","dataValue":"eyJjb2RlIjoiNTBfMl8wNjAwMDUyQTdDNzUwQTc4QTkzRDAxNTRDODg5QzYwQTk3Q0JDMkZDMUUwNjBBRDM4QUMyMzcwNUI0NDZERTQzNkU0REJGRkNGQ0VDQTFGNEY1NjRDNUMzNzUzMDAxM0U3MjYwMDA3IiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NTkzNTEyMDU3ODcyMzUwNDA0NjAyIiwidiI6IjEuMSJ9"},"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}
```

Thanks in advance,

Waleed

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that you are referring to?

Comment: @JohnConde https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html  pls find heading "Handling the Response" on the page

Comment: According to the documentation this is only returned when using the hosted form. I would have to assume that is not true in your case.

Comment: I am using hosted form, for hosted form we need to use button like mentioned above